# How to automatically remove event reference in asp.net webcontrol when event is deleted from C# codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, exception, webforms

Everytime I accidentally doubleclick a webcontrol (ex GridView, DetailsView), VS creates an 
unnecessary event in code (selectedindexchanged). I delete this event, but the reference still appears in webcontrol's properties, causing the CS1061 exception.

Is there a way to delete the reference in properties (or asp.net code) automatically when the event is deleted in C# code?

I know that when programming in VB, Visual Studio does it, so i'm looking for a similar solution in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem as you before and while it's not really a problem, I feel your frustration when you run and then it all fails because you forgot to remove the code from the .aspx.
Unfortunately there's no way to change this behavior. No automatic way to do it, anyway. I too looked for a solution for this a while back and found literally nothing despite my hopes of finding a hidden option within Visual Studio.
It's only a little time taken from you though, so you should be alright.